# NodeJS Docker-compose, Cannot link to a non running container

Tags: php, node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have this docker stack running nginx, php, and mariadb.
Now I want to add NodeJS in order to migrate my platform to services, one at the time.

I'm trying to add node in the same way I added php,but when I run "docker-compose up", nodejs appears "Exited with code 254".
It appears to be a ENOET error related with my package.json file, but I'm already coping my file into the container, also if I run everything less nodejs, when I access my nginx container the package.json appears in the route it means to be, so I don't know why I'm seeing this error.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
nginx:
    image: tutum/nginx
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "8080:8080"
        # - "8081:8081"
        # - "8082:8082"
        # - "8083:8083"
        # - "8090:8090"
    links:
        - nodejs
        - phpfpm
        - mariadb
    volumes:
        - ./public/leal-api:/var/www
        - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
        - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

        - ./public:/usr/share/nginx/html

nodejs:
    command: npm start
    build: ./node    
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    links:
        - mariadb
    volumes:
        - ./public/leal-api:/var/www

phpfpm:
    build: ./php
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    links:
        - mariadb
    volumes:
        - ./public:/usr/share/nginx/html
mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: leal
        MYSQL_USER: lealadm
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: leal2015*
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: LealColombia2017!
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
```

And here is the Dockerfile of the nodejs

```
FROM node:7.10


VOLUME ["/var/www"]

# WORKDIR /src
WORKDIR /var/www

# COPY . /src

# RUN npm install
# RUN npm install -g nodemon #hmm idk

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide.